# android app crashes when setting task description

Tags: android, android-studio

i m trying to set task description using the following code

```
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {

        String title = "F App";
        int icon = R.drawable.circle;
        int color = R.color.red;

        ActivityManager.TaskDescription description = new ActivityManager.TaskDescription(title, icon, color);
        this.setTaskDescription(description);

    }
```

and this is the error log

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No direct method <init>(Ljava/lang/String;II)V in class Landroid/app/ActivityManager$TaskDescription; or its super classes (declaration of 'android.app.ActivityManager$TaskDescription' appears in /system/framework/framework.jar)
        at com.myapp.app.main.home.galaxy.FAppActivity.onViewsInitialised(FAppActivity.java:36)
        at com.myapp.app.common.BaseActivity.onCreate(BaseActivity.java:47)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7030)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7021)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2773)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2898)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1624)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6549)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:888)
```

i seached through some of the threads[not with adjact error but somewhat similar] and found out that some dependency might be using an older version of support library and which might not have the method. i dont know if that thing affects !

in my app.gradle i m using `androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0` and compile sdk version `28` and sdk tools version `28.0.3`

please help if you know anything about such issues

Comment: how did you solve it finally?

Comment: @AsthaGarg i used 3 args constructor with Bitmap as icon

Comment: Ya thanks that solves the error but shows as this method deprecated and int  ResId one is latest. Do you know the supported sdk version for 3 paramets with bitmap vs with int res id?

Answer (score 1):

You are using [a three argument constructor](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.TaskDescription#ActivityManager.TaskDescription(java.lang.String,%20int,%20int)) that is only available at API.28 (Android P)

If you want to use API 21, you have to use the [one-argument constructor](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.TaskDescription#ActivityManager.TaskDescription(java.lang.String)) or the deprecated [3-argument constructor](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.TaskDescription#ActivityManager.TaskDescription(java.lang.String,%20android.graphics.Bitmap,%20int)) that uses a `Bitmap` instead of a icon int resource.

So to make your code works

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {

    String title = "F App";
    int icon = R.drawable.circle;
    int color = R.color.red;

    ActivityManager.TaskDescription description = new ActivityManager.TaskDescription(title, icon, color);
    this.setTaskDescription(description);

} else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {

    String title = "F App";
    Bitmap icon = .....
    int color = R.color.red;

    ActivityManager.TaskDescription description = new ActivityManager.TaskDescription(title, icon, color);
    this.setTaskDescription(description);

}
```

Comment: this makes no sense. i m using sdk version 28. so i can obviously use the 3 args constructor. also the code you have provided has nothing new. its just copy paste from question. it would have been better if you comment that thing down.

Comment: and three args constructor had been available since API 21 the only thing that changed is the type of second argument. initially it use to accept bitmap and now it asks for icon resource id. `API 28` => https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.TaskDescription#ActivityManager.TaskDescription(java.lang.String,%20int,%20int) and `API 21` => https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.TaskDescription#ActivityManager.TaskDescription(java.lang.String,%20android.graphics.Bitmap,%20int)

Comment: @example How you are using SDK 28 and wrapping your code within `Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP`  which is `API 21` ?

Comment: @example also you are not using the `API 21` Bitmap icon version; if you need to do that you'll be using a deprecated code. still you are using the `int` version of the second argument which is only available at `API 28` .. That is miss-copying of seeing it 29.. I corrected it in answer.  keep calm bro

Comment: and API 28 is obviously greater than 21. moreover if what you are saying would have been the case then android studio would have given me lint errors and it would never install the app

Comment: @example anyway android will run your code normally if you are using code beyond your minimum API level, but it will just warns you .. I am sure that API 28 is android p .. check [this](https://source.android.com/setup/start/build-numbers) out .. we here learn from one another .. stay safe!

Comment: if my min sdk support is 16 it won't even get installed on devices lower than that

Comment: @example you can only use `ActivityManager.TaskDescription` starting from API.21, so if your app min API level is 16; you have to use an alternative solution .. but that was not the gist of your question... you just was asking about  how to solve `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError`